# type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype 'List<Map<String,Object>>' of function... flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dictionary, object, widget

I've got variable

```
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {'page': Page1(), 'title': 'Page1'},
    {'page': Page2(), 'title': 'Page2'}
  ];
```

and then in the appBar title I want to use this variable

```
 title: Text(_pages[1]['title']),
```

But I get error

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'List<Map<String,Object>>'....

I've tried to use dynamic instead of Object, that did not help.
Is there any way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
 title: Text(((_pages[1])['title']).toString()),
```

Comment: VScode throws error >  The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'